# Convert curl to Java HttpPost

Tags: java, apache, http, curl

I'm having some trouble converting a curl command to a java httpPost. I'm trying to contact the Census Bureau Address Batch endpoint. I can contact it but I get a response stating something is incorrect.

The curl command is on the last page of this https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/Geocoding_Services_API.pdf

The required parameters state it needs benchmark, vintage and addressFile so I'm trying to use each. The addressFile itself is a csv that I got here https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/addressbatch?form

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response;

try {
    String url = "https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/addressbatch"
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    MultipartEntity postEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    postEntity.addPart("addressFile", new FileBody(new File("addresses.csv")));
    postEntity.addPart("benchmark", new StringBody("Public_AR_Current"));
    postEntity.addPart("vintage", new StringBody("Public_AR_Current"));

    httpPost.setEntity(postEntity);

    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

    StringWriter writerResponse = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(responseEntity.getContent(), writerResponse, "UTF-8");

    print response.getStatusLine()

    print writerResponse.toString()

} catch (IOException e) {
    print e
}
finally {
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

So doing it like this I get a code 400 error

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>
> While attempting to geocode your batch
>   input, an error occurred validating and processing the parameters that
>   were provided.
>
> Please validate the benchmark, vintage (if
>   this is a geographies batch geocode request), and addressFile
>   parameter values that are being used and retry your batch geocode
>   request.
>
> More information and documentation (available in
>   HTML and PDF formats) about the Census Geocoder and how to use it can
>   be found here: https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/'>https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/

Any thoughts on what I'm doing incorrectly? The response isn't very specific as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The values for benchmark and vintage are not valid, one of the possible values is 4 for both, check other possible values inspecting the network call in developer tool (mozilla)

Comment: Hey thanks for this. It looks like both vintage and benchmark need integer strings and not the name. Using "4" for both works and gets me a 200 reponse, so I'll figure out what those number represent.

Comment: I tested with same code with value `"4"` for benchmark and vintage instead `"Public_AR_Current"` and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the API instructions are incorrect. The vintage and benchmark parameters need strings with integer values rather than strings with the names of the benchmark/vintages.